# Show content on link_to using hover (rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, hover, link-to, mousehover

Currently I have a link_to that when clicked it opens a popup. I want to add a function so that when I hover on the link it shows certain content. I want to show the users who liked a post similar to facebook likes when you mouseover.

Upon hover I want to show who liked the post via

```
render micropost.voters_who_voted
```

microposts/_micropost:

```
<%= link_to into_it_micropost_path(micropost.id), :onclick => "javascript:window.open('/microposts/#{micropost.id}/into_it','popup','width=285,height=300,top=315,left=200');", id: "feeditemlikes_#{micropost.id}", remote: true do %>
  <%= "#{micropost.votes_for} Into it!" %>
    <ul class="likes">
      <%= render micropost.voters_who_voted %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

CSS:

```
[id^=feeditemlikes] {
  .likes { display: none; }
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $blue;
    .likes { display: block; }
}
```

}

Comment: So, does the code you posted work or not? Also, what does "Upon hover I want to <code>" mean? You want to do what?

Comment: The code I posted works. But it doesn't show the content upon a mouse hover, I do not know how to do that part. When I mouse over that link_to I obviously want it to show something right? Well that code is what I want to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show certain content on hover using CSS, then that content must be a child element of the element that receives `:hover` (in this case the link). For example:

ERB:

```
<%= link_to into_it_micropost_path(micropost.id), :onclick => "javascript:window.open('/microposts/#{micropost.id}/into_it','popup','width=285,height=300,top=315,left=200');", id: "feeditemlikes_#{micropost.id}", remote: true do %>
  <%= "#{micropost.votes_for} Into it!" %>
  <ul class="users">
    <%= render @user.names %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

SCSS:

```
[id^=feeditemlikes] {
  .users { display: none; }
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $blue;
    .users { display: block; }
  }
}
```

(By the way, instead of using `[id^=feeditemlikes]`, I would put a class on the link and refer to that. See below.)

But if you want to show content on hover that is not a child element of the link, then you need to use JavaScript.

Here's an example using CoffeeScript and jQuery:

```
$('a.feed-item-likes').hover ->
  $('.users').toggle()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin like this:  http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/  To create a tooltip when hovering over the link.  What you do is have your view-level code print out the content in a title tag for the link, and the plugin will pop it up for you.